# Split String in N pieces by a set of index

Tags: java, split

Could someone help me to get a String and brake this in N pieces by passing a set of indexes...

For example

Set of index = (0,3,7,10);

And brake a String by theses indexes

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? I think you will have to implement your own algorithm for it

Comment: Use `String#substring(int,int)`

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing it with a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
  if (i == indexes.length -1) {
    string.substring(indexes[i]);
  } else {
    string.substring(indexes[i], indexes[i+1]);
  }
}
```

capturing the substrings into some appropriate container (a List or an array, depending)

Comment: @MrLore Yes, i meant to use a comparison ==.  Good thing the Java compiler catches and reports such errors, as opposed to its accommodating cousin, C. Will edit to fix.